# Reuse validation method. Convert object

Tags: java

I have two similar class objects. I have a couple of methods for the first class object wich I also want to reuse for my second class object but I'm not sure how and I don't want to write duplicate methods.

I extracted and simplified an example to show how i think.

first class

```
public class FirstClass {
    int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    ...
}
```

Second class

```
 public class SecondClass {
        int number;

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Third class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass();
        firstClass.setNumber(5);
        SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();
        secondClass.setNumber(5);

        numberIsFive(firstClass);
        numberIsFive(secondClass);
    }

    public void numberIsFive(Object myObject){
        if(myObject instanceof FirstClass){
            myObject = (FirstClass)myObject;
        }else if(myObject instanceof SecondClass){
            myObject = (SecondClass)myObject;
        }

        if(myObject.getNumber() == 5){
            System.out.println("is five");
        }else{
            System.out.println("is not five");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

and no numberIsIFive(firsclass.getNumber()) is not an option since the methods I use have much more validations.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case that might be "over-engineering", but in general you would look towards **composition** here, like:

```
interface IntValueHolder {
  int getNumber();
  void setNumber(int value);
}

class IntValueHolderImpl implements IntValueHolder { ...
```

And then you would "drop" the code that you currently have in both of your classes, and instead, both classes would (somehow) have an instance of IntValueHolder.

In your case, it might be more appropriate to simple have your two classes implement that "common" interface IntValueHolder - to at least avoid that repeated instanceof calls and downcast (down to a specific class).

Edit: of course, another option would be to use inheritance here - make your two classes derive from some base class that provides this behavior. But using inheritance just to avoid code duplication is most of the time a bad idea. Classes inherit from each other because that makes "sense" in the underlying model, not to save a line of code.

Comment: What about using Inheritance?

Comment: All answers where really good thanks. I accepted this one tough because it was the one closest to the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

Before continuing I recommend you to read about it and other object oriented programming concepts by yourself.

Focusing on this particular case, you should create a base class such as

```
public class BaseClass {
    int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Which includes all common fields and methods of your `FirstClass` and `SecondClass`. Then remove those methods from your two current classes, and just create them as `public class FirstClass extends BaseClass` to give them BaseClass functionality.

Finally, you'd have to change your validation method, to only accept objects that belong to your base class by making it like this `public void numberIsFive(BaseClass myObject)` (as a general rule you'll have much less errors by accepting a specific class in a method, rather than accepting any old object).

Edit: Other answerers are correct and Inheritance is also a valid solution. Which one you use would depend on what makes more sense in the context of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)) and apply it in both classes, then make your validation method receive an interface instead of an `Object`

Example:

```
public interface Number {

    int get();

    void set(int n);
}
```

Then your classes will look like this:

```
public class FirstClass implements Number {

    int number;

    @Override
    public int get() {
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int n) {
        this.number = n;
    }
}
```

And your validation method receives a Number:

```
public void numberIsFive(Number myNumber){
 ...
}
```

Comment: I guess tyou wanted to write public void numberIsFive(Number myNumber){